# npm run -- if start command entered manually it throws error command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I am going through the electron [quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) repo. it has npm package.json file

which is like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  }
```

here is the [package.json](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/package.json) file.

The npm documentation says it will run the command that is specified in "start" under the "scripts" section of the package.json file. In the absence of that section will do `node server.js` [npm doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start.html)

Now I am trying to run the start command manually on the terminal but I am receiving "command not found" error.  `npm start` will run fine without throwing an error.

Now I am confused about how `npm start` is able to execute it and why I am receiving command not found error.

Comment: so `electron` says command not found?

Comment: Have you installed Node.js (and its package manager "npm")? https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that `electron` binary from locally installed `electron` package is executed. This is supported by NPM scripts.

It can be run from a terminal with globally installed [`npx`](https://github.com/zkat/npx) package or by running the binary from relative path, with project root as current working directory:

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron
```

Comment: `./node_modules/.bin/electron .` would replicate what npm start is doing.